# Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server IIS

Tags: asp.net, web, iis

Asp.NET  website published on IIS on some server.
The site working correctly, when browsing this website from the server which contains it the site working without problem.
I browse with Url `http://localhost/TR/Login.aspx`
every thing ok.

When I am trying to reach the website from the outside of the server using its ip address I am getting the following error

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Before giving a suggestion, keep in mind that I checked the following

1. firewall of the server is not working
2. inbound/outbound rules have been created for the port of the website in the firewall
3. I added a binding to the website which contains the IP address of the server and specified the port
4. The Security tab of the website contains IIS_IUSERS exists and all the permissions for it are "allow"
5. Even I added this to the web.config

   ```
   <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
      <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
   ```
6. I opended the CMD from my machine and I throw ping to IP of the server, and I received the ping back

Comment: Check what error code is there in IIS log files, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Comment: did you set **NETWORK SERVICE** permission to the site folder?